# How to internationalize the sub menu name "categories" in Custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, translation

I'm trying for translation. I made a plugin with custom post type everything is okay. Only one thing i can't able to translate which is `categories` sub menu menu in custom post type.

```
$args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'taxonomies' => array('category','mypost')
);
```

for the `$labels` i translated easily but here for the category i can't able to translate.

If i do __() in the array of taxonomies then the category is not at all coming because that might be translate so the wordpress can't able to recognize the argument. How to translate categories sub menu in my custom post type menu?

Is there any way to rename it? Because from the rename i guess i can translate

Comment: What is those categories in your case? Are you applying native  categories taxonomy to your CPT? In that case its translations should be coming from core just fine.

Comment: Yes am using the default native categories. How to translate that. Thanks @Rarst

Comment: Do native categories appear translated elsewhere, such as on native posts menu section, etc?